# Querying nested associations with includes instead of joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have join statement:

```
Event.joins(artists: :followers)
```

I need access to `follower`'s attributes, so I'd like to eager load it with `includes` and `references`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to eager load your associations and access the *first* `follower` for the *first* `artist` of the *first* `event` (according to your code, each association represents one-to-many relation, thus each associated relation is a collection, not a single object):

```
events = Event.includes(artists: :followers).references(:artists, :followers)

follower = events.first.artists.first.followers.first
```